# Showing that surface area is equivalent to $\int_{S}\|\partial_u\phi\times\partial_v\phi\|dudv$, and is there MVT for bijections: $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, solution-verification, surfaces, riemann-sum

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$It can be shown that arclength, considered as a sum of increasingly fine partitions of the graph, approaches the integral formulation. However, I have only ever seen the surface area integral treated as a definition, or as a truth, and today I wish to prove it - my proof is quite unwieldy, so I'm not sure if it's rigorous or if it can be cleaned up. I also don't study differential geometry, so I'd like to know if my reasoning and terminology is consistent with the field. As soon as I saw the above formula I knew I had to attempt a proof, so here it is:

Definitions:

> Let $M$ be a smooth surface if: $M\subset\Bbb R^3$ is bounded and of null Lebesgue measure and there exists a simply connected open $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ together with a $C^2$ bijection $\varphi:\Omega\to M$.
>
> Let $P=\{x_{i,j}\in M:i,j\in\{1,\cdots,N\}\}$ be a partition of a smooth surface $M$ if $\{x_{i,j}:j\in\{1,\cdots,N\}\}$ partitions a contour in $M$ for any fixed $1\le i\le N$ and visa versa. Define the area of $P$ to be the sum of areas of the triangles with vertices $\{x_{i,j},x_{i,j+1},x_{i+1,j}\}$ and $\{x_{i+1,j},x_{i+1,j+1},x_{i,j+1}\}$.

Note: I chose to define it via triangles as triangles are always coplanar, whereas when I attempted this before with quadrilaterals I ran into problems - decomposing the quadrilaterals into two triangles seems to work!

> Define the surface area of a smooth surface $M$ to be the limit of the areas of the partitions of $M$ as $\max\{\max_{i,j}\{x_{i+1,j}-x_{i,j}\},\max_{i,j}\{x_{i,j+1}-x_{i,j}\}\}\to0$, if it exists.
>
> If $S\subset\Bbb R^3$ can be decomposed as the disjoint union of finitely many $M_1,M_2,\cdots,M_n$ smooth surfaces with parametristations $(\Omega_1,\varphi_1),\cdots,(\Omega_n,\varphi_n)$, then it has a surface area equivalent to the sum of the surface areas of the $M_k$.

I am a touch worried that there may be pathological surfaces for which this doesn't work but I think this is all ok so far.

Let $Q$ be an arbitrary rectangular partition into points $(u_i,v_i)_{i=1}^N$ of a smooth surface $\Omega$, and put $\Delta Q=\max\{\max_i\{u_{i+1}-u_i\},\max_i\{v_{i+1}-v_i\}\}$. As $\varphi$ is a continuous bijection, $\varphi(Q)$ will be a valid partition of $M=\varphi(\Omega)$. Consider for any fixed $i$ the two triangles described by the points $(u_i,v_j),(u_{i+1},v_j),(u_i,v_{j+1}),(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})$. The corresponding area of the two triangles in the partition of $M$, $P=\varphi(Q)$, will be: $$\frac{1}{2}\|(\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\times(\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\|$$And: $$\frac{1}{2}\|(\varphi(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1}))\times(\varphi(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j))\|$$

EDIT: As per Matteo's comment, I've now realised that the MVT fails not only for functions with multidimensional domain, but also for functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$. I think the bijectivity of $\varphi$ saves the proof, but it will require more work that I cannot straight away think of.

CONT:

As $\varphi$ is $C^2$, one may employ the mean value theorem twice by holding $u$ or $v$ fixed and letting the other vary, making the function defined $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$, so defining $\Delta u_i=u_{i+1}-u_i$ and similarly for $\Delta v_j$ gives: $$\begin{align}\varphi(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})&=\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j)+\varphi(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})\\&\hspace{10pt}-\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-(\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\\&=\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j)+\Delta v_j\cdot(\partial_v\varphi(u_{i+1},\theta_v)-\partial_v\varphi(u_i,\theta_v))\\&=\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j)+\Delta v_j\Delta u_i\cdot\partial^2_{uv}(\theta_u,\theta_v)\\\varphi(u_{i+1},v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)&=\cdots\\&=\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j)+\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\cdot\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\end{align}$$

For mean values $\theta_u,\vartheta_u\in(u_i,u_{i+1}),\,\theta_v,\vartheta_v\in(v_j,v_{j+1})$.

Then the second area becomes: $$\frac{1}{2}\|(\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\times(\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\|\\\hspace{80pt}\\\hspace{20pt}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\left\{\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times(\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\|\\\hspace{40pt}+\|(\varphi(u_{i+1},v_j)-\varphi(u_i,v_j))\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\\\hspace{30pt}+\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\cdot\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\right\}$$

Employ the mean value theorem once more with feeling to the expressions of the form $\varphi(u_i,v_{j+1})-\varphi(u_i,v_j)$, using mean values $\lambda_u,\lambda_v$ in the appropriate ranges, and the two areas become:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\|\partial_u\varphi(\lambda_u,v_j)\times\partial_v\varphi(u_i,\lambda_v)\|$$

And:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\|\partial_u\varphi(\lambda_u,v_j)\times\partial_v\varphi(u_i,\lambda_v)\|+\\\hspace{20pt}\frac{1}{2}\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\left\{\Delta v_j\cdot\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times\partial_v\varphi(u_i,\lambda_v)\|+\Delta u_i\cdot\|\partial_u\varphi(\lambda_u,v_j)\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\\\hspace{30pt}+\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\cdot\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\right\}$$

The area of the partition $P=\varphi(Q)$ is then expressible as (by summing the two triangles per summand):

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{N-1}\|\partial_u\varphi(\lambda_u,v_j)\times\partial_v(u_i,\lambda_v)\|\cdot\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\\+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{N-1}\left\{\Delta v_j\cdot\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times\partial_v\varphi(u_i,\lambda_v)\|+\Delta u_i\cdot\|\partial_u\varphi(\lambda_u,v_j)\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\\\hspace{30pt}+\Delta u_i\Delta v_j\cdot\|\partial^2_{uv}\varphi(\theta_u,\theta_v)\times\partial^2_{vu}\varphi(\vartheta_u,\vartheta_v)\|\right\}\cdot\Delta u_i\Delta v_j$$

As $\Delta Q\to0$, the latter sum clearly goes to $0$ as it features quadratic $\Delta$ terms, and by considering the first sum as a Riemann sum over a double partition tagged with the values $\lambda$, in the passage to the limit (if it exists) we find that the surface area is:

$$A(M)=\iint_{\Omega}\left\|\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v}\right\|\d u\d v$$

And:

$$A(S)=\sum_{k=1}^n\iint_{\Omega_k}\left\|\frac{\partial\varphi_k}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\varphi_k}{\partial v}\right\|\d u\d v$$

Is this a correct proof? And is the preliminary definition a sensible one? Furthermore, I expect that the $C^2$ condition can be dropped but I don't see how. It would have certainly been easier to consider quadrilaterals rather than triangles, but my attempts at that failed on the realisation that four points need not be coplanar, and thus need not be a good approximation to the surface - finding the area and creating good partitions was tricky. Hopefully my triangle approach works!

Comment: Sorry, I think one issue could be the use of the mean value theorem for a vector valued
 functions. Take for example $t\to (cos(t),sin(t))$ and the values $0$ and $2\pi.$ But I think you are on the right track, and the proof could be adjusted for normal sets. I only have one reference for this proof but it's in Italian: Analisi matematica II: funzioni di più variabili, authors Jaures P.Cecconi and Guido Stampacchia. Guido Stampacchia was a great boss in the branch of the Calculus of variations!

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi I dodged around the MVT's failure in multiple dimensions by locking $u_i,v_i$ fixed, and then taking the map $f:v\mapsto\varphi(u_i,v)-\varphi(u_i,v_i)$ as a continuous function from $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$, and then using MVT on $f(v_{i+1})$. I believe this is legitimate

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi I welcome learning resources in any language - feel free to link the reference if you want!

Comment: I should think about it, because $\varphi$ is still vector valued.

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi You're right. I think however that the bijectivity of $\varphi$ saves it, but it will require more work!

Comment: https://www.amazon.it/Analisi-matematica-Jaures-P-Cecconi/dp/8820710226 this is the book I was referring to.

Comment: I wish you well!

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi And you

Comment: Are you aware of the famous Schwarz example of polygons inscribed in a finite cylinder whose total area approaches infinity? This is pictured in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* (p. 129) or Volume 1 of his *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* (p. 354).

Comment: @TedShifrin ... No! My only access to diff. geo. is your text, but I haven't studied it yet. I did scan it in case there was a proof of the surface area integral, but sadly none that I could find. Hopefully the Schwarz example does not apply to my triangular mesh, as if that fails then I have no idea how to approach this problem

Comment: This is really unrelated to differential geometry. It's just about surface integrals and how one has to be very careful with what an appropriate "triangular mesh" should mean. I drew the picture for my multivariable mathematics book, so I'll upload it into an answer, even though I'm not doing the work to see if this answers your question or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the famous Schwarz example of a triangular mesh inscribed in a finite cylinder and the total surface area goes to infinity as we move the planes of the hexagons closer and closer. I am not sure if this gives a counterexample to your procedure or not, but I'll let you ponder it.

[image: Schwarz example]

P.S. The bijectivity of the mapping won't rescue the Mean Value *Equality*. Consider $\phi(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$. Instead of the domain $[0,2\pi]$, take $[0,2\pi-\epsilon]$. Now $\|\phi(2\pi-\epsilon)-\phi(0)\|<\epsilon$, but $\|(2\pi-\epsilon)\phi'(\xi)\| = 2\pi-\epsilon$ for any $\xi\in (0,2\pi-\epsilon)$, so we cannot have $\phi(2\pi-\epsilon)-\phi(0) = (2\pi-\epsilon)\phi'(\xi)$ for any $\xi$.

Comment: Thank you for this Sir. Does Schwarz's lantern use points not on the on the cylinder itself? Visually it does, whereas my process uses only points on the surface, so I'm hoping that avoids this pathology.

Comment: The vertices are all on the cylinder, yes. Sorry, the $\ell$ for the length of the side of the hexagon got lost in converting the graphic. But $\ell$ and $h$ stay constant. We just use more and hexagons spaced closer and closer.

Comment: I see. It’s good to have learned of this pathology. I hope I can show some amended MVT for bijections and salvage my proof, but if I can’t do you have any hints for finding the surface area - cross product - integral? It’s referenced in your book but as a fact rather than a theorem to be shown

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to take as a definition of the surface area. If you learn either differential forms (and use the $2$-form that assigns the value $1$ to each oriented orthonormal basis of the tangent space) or Hausdorff measure (see, for example, Frank Morgan's *Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide*), you can give rigorous definitions. I think that if you're going to use mesh approximations, you're going to have to make sure they converge in a much stronger sense (e.g., angles with the tangent planes getting smaller).

Comment: Ah. Not salvageable I see; thank you for your help. I am familiar with measure theory but not differential geometry; do you integrate the measure of the pullback of the surface by $\varphi$ multiplied by some Jacobian? Or is it more complicated

Comment: You really need $2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure to get a natural measure on a two-dimensional subset of $\Bbb R^3$. With smooth submanifolds, you can get a $2$-form by contracting the volume form of $\Bbb R^3$ against the unit normal of the surface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are bumping into the Schwarz paradox, which is a counter-example demonstrating the failure of  the naive approach to defining surface area by inscribed polyhedra.
The counter-example consists of a circular cylinder that is formed from a rectangular sheet of paper that is partitioned into triangular cells. The polyhedral approximations fail to converge to the expected area unless very specific conditions are imposed on how the partitioning is performed in each of the two directions on the rectangular sheet.

The following is a quote from *"On the circumradius condition for piecewise linear triangular elements"* by
Kenta Kobayashi · Takuya Tsuchiya
**Japan J. Indust. Appl. Math. (2015) 32:65–76**

N.B. The mathematical formulas were re-typeset by hand, and they differ slightly in layout from that of the original paper. I hope that no errors were introduced in the process.

> As is well understood, the length of a curve is defined as the limit
> of the length of the inscribed polygonal edges. Hence, one might think
> that the area of a surface could be defined in a similar manner.
> Actually, mathematicians in the 19th century believed that the area of
> surface is the limit of the areas of inscribed polygonal surfaces. In
> the 1880s, Schwarz and Peano independently showed, however, that this
> definition does not work.

Let $R$ be a rectangle of height $H$ and width $2πr$.

> Let $m, n$ be positive integers. Suppose that this rectangle is
> divided into $m$ equal strips, each of height $H/m$. Each strip is
> then divided into isosceles triangles whose base length is $2πr/n$.
> Then, the cylinder is approximated by the inscribed polygonal surface
> which consists of $2mn$ congruent isosceles triangles. Because the
> height of ­ each triangle is $\sqrt{(H/m)^2 + r^2(1 − \cos(\pi/n))^2}$
> and the base length is $2r \sin(\pi/n)$,
>
> the area  of the inscribed polygonal surface is  ­
> $A= 2mnr\sin(\pi/n) \sqrt{ (H/m)^2 +r^2 (1−\cos(\pi/n))^2}$
>
> $= 2πr  \frac{ \sin(\pi/n)}{\pi/n} \sqrt{H^2+ \frac{\pi^4 r^2 }{4} \frac{ m^2}{n^4} (\frac{ \sin(\pi/(2n))}{(\pi/2n)})^4 }$

which tends to the traditional surface area definition $A= 2\pi RH$ if and only if $(m/n^2)\to 0$.
­